# How do I set the location of Radio Buttons?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jradiobutton, flowlayout

I want to create two radio buttons for the "Gender" label. Here is what I got:

```
maleRB = new JRadioButton("Male", true);
femaleRB = new JRadioButton("Female", false);

radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
radioGroup.add(maleRB);
radioGroup.add(femaleRB);
```

But I have no idea on how to set their locations. Do you set the location the same as how you set the location of JLabel/JTextField, etc...? Here is the photo. I want to place the radio buttons beside the label "Gender".

[image: IMG]

Comment: Depends on the Layout Manager you're using

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton

Comment: you can add the radio group within Panel and set the layout for it

Comment: _Do you set the location the same as how you set the location of JLabel/JTextField, etc..._ Yes, you use a LayoutManager to do that. Never call yourself `setLocation/setSize/setBounds/setPreferredSize`!

Answer (score 2):

It generally depends on which layout you are using, but one way to add the radio button group is via `JPanel` as i mentioned in the comment earlier.

```
JRadioButton maleRB   = new JRadioButton("Male"  , true);
JRadioButton femaleRB    = new JRadioButton("Female"   , false);

ButtonGroup bgroup = new ButtonGroup();
bgroup.add(maleRB);
bgroup.add(femaleRB);

JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(r, c)); // here r could be 1 and c could be 2 
radioPanel.add(maleRB);
radioPanel.add(femaleRB);
```

Comment: I have a problem. I tried this, but it doesn't show up in the frame. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just add them to a JPanel the same way you would anything else.

`ButtonGroup` just wires their events together so that only one can be selected at once. It isn't a graphical Swing component itself.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Just do

`button.setbounds(x,y,z,w);  // your coordinates,length and width button.setLayout(null);`

Answer (score -2):

```
YourButton.setBounds(X, Y, Z, MAX_ENTRIES);
```

Example:

```
Duck.setBounds(75, 100, 75, MAX_ENTRIES);
```